# Measuring time of execution on method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say we have this:

```
function myMethod1() {
    ...
}
```

and later in the code:

```
myMethod1();
alert('myMethod1() was executed!');
```

I need to set timeout for the alert so that it will be called after myMethod1() executes. But how do I know the value of the second parameter for the setTimeout function? How do I measure the time needed for myMethod1() to execute?

MyMethod1() has an async ajax call.

Comment: your method returns before it's completed?

Comment: short of a timemachine there is no way of guessing how long a function will still take to run. forget what you are trying.

Comment: Unless myMethod1 does a AJAX call (asynchronous) it will be already called after each other.

Comment: @Scree: Then you can only do `myMethod1(); alert('myMethod1() was executed, the ajax was started!');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your method performs an asynchronous task, it's common to pass a callback function like so:

```
function myMethod(cb)
{
    // some code, such as $.ajax
    $.ajax({
         url: 'example.com',
         complete: function() {
             // we're done, notify callback
             cb();
         }
    });
}
```

Then, `cb` is passed in like this upon execution:

```
myMethod(function() {
    alert('method is done');
});
alert('method returned, but is still doing stuff in the background');
```

This is the mantra of asynchronous design; every method that performs a task in the background will have some way of notifying a callback function of its completion.

---

If the method is synchronous however, you could call `cb()` at the end of the function body, but it would be much easier to keep what you had:

```
myMethod();
alert('method is done');
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to. The way that you have set it up, the `alert` will always fire **after** `myMethod1()` finishes.

Comment: Unless myMethod1 does something asynchronous like a AJAX call.

Comment: the method has an async ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a time stamp, will be precise to the millisecond.

You'll need 2 vars, one to hold the start time and one for the end tume.
And to set those var, where you want to calculate. So

///EDITED version below to make it global..

put this at he top of you js code:

```
var ts_start;
var ts_stop;
```

put this where you want to START calculating the time:

```
ts_start =new Date().getTime();
```

put this where you want to STOP calculating the time:

```
ts_stop =new Date().getTime();
```

and you can alert the millesecond by making the diff bewteen them.

```
alert(ts_stop-ts_start);
```

OR shove it in a variable...